# Understanding String encoding/decoding Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a program I run with mvn exec:java (my main file is encoded in utf-8 and the default charset of my system is windows-1252)

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); //print windows-1252
String s = "éàè";
System.out.println(new String(s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))); //OK Print éàè
System.out.println(new String(s.getBytes(Charset.forName("windows-1252")))); //Not OK Print ▒▒▒
```

I don't understand why the first print works, according to the documentation getBytes **encodes the String into a sequence of bytes using the given charset** and the String constructor **constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset**

So the first print encodes in UTF-8 and then decode with the platform's default charset which is windows-1252, how could this workd ? It cannot decode the encoded utf-8 byte array using the platform charset windows-1252.

The second print is wrong, I don't understand why. As my file is encoded in utf-8 and the platform charset is windows-1252, my intention is to encode the String with windows-1252 charset so I call s.getBytes(Charset.forName("windows-1252")) and then create a String with the previous result but it doesn't work

Comment: Try `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "windows-1252");
out.println(s);`

Comment: As a sidenote, the MS-DOS default charset is not 1252, see here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "windows-1252");  doesn't work but PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8"); does

Comment: @Berger you are right, I am using MinGW to execute my program, with MS-DOS the program works correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String` value `éàè` is encoded in UTF-8 as byte octets `0xC3 0xA9 0xC3 0xA0 0xC3 0xA8`.  Those same byte octets interpreted as Windows-1252 are the String value `Ã©Ã<nbsp>Ã¨` (where `<nbsp>` is a *non-breaking space* character, Unicode codepoint `U+00A0`).

In the first example, you are converting a `String` to the above UTF-8 bytes, and then you are converting the bytes back to a `String` using Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.  So you should be getting a new `String` value of `Ã©Ã<nbsp>Ã¨`, not `éàè`. You are then writing that `String` to the console, so it gets encoded using Windows-1252 back to byte octets `0xC3 0xA9 0xC3 0xA0 0xC3 0xA8`, which should be displayed as `Ã©Ã<nbsp>Ã¨` (or something similar to it) if the console is displaying the bytes as-is.  On the other hand, if the console is configured for UTF-8 instead, those bytes would display as `éàè` when interpreted as UTF-8.

In the second example, since you are using Windows-1252 for both encoding and decoding, and the particular characters in question are supported by Windows-1252, you should end up with the original `String` value `éàè` before writing it to the console.  If that `String` gets encoded to bytes using Windows-1252, and the console is configured for UTF-8, it would make sense why you don't see `éàè` displayed.  The `String` value `éàè` is encoded in Windows-1252 as byte octets `0xE9 0xE0 0xE8`, which is not a valid UTF-8 byte octet sequence.

In short, the behavior you are seeing would happen when your console is configured to interpret outgoing bytes as UTF-8, but you are not giving it proper UTF-8 encoded bytes as output.

Comment: This is a restatement of the question, not an answer. If you are asserting that his console is set to UTF-8, you should lead off with that.

Comment: I did not just restate the question.  The question is asking to understand how the encodings are behaving differently than expected.  I think I answered that.

Comment: The lede was buried. It makes more sense now with the concluding paragraph.

Comment: exact @RemyLebeau, I forgot to take in consideration the encoding of the console. Effectively, the result differs whether I use MinGW console or  MS-DOS